# With ansible playbook only copy files that are changed or new

Tags: ansible

I have a list of files in src_directory and I want to copy them to dest_directory, and I have the code to do just that:

```
  - name: Check if exist MYFILES ls -1 {{ src_directory }}/mfiles/ | wc -l
    shell: ls -1 {{ src_directory }}/mfiles/ | wc -l
    register: exist_mfiles
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
 
  - name:  Copy MYFILES
    copy:
     src: "{{ src_directory }}/mfiles/"
     dest: "{{ dest_directory }}/mfiles/"
     force: yes
     mode: '664'
    when: exist_mfiles.stdout != "0"
```

### The problem:

The problem is that the files are large and there are many of them, and when connection errors occur, it takes a long time to copy them again.

### The question:

How can I copy only **new** and **changed** files?

Comment: Just by using [`synchronize` module – A wrapper around rsync to make common tasks in your playbooks quick and easy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) instead.